# Call Views from subfolders with one Controller Asp.Net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, project-structure

I am trying to use a controller for multiple views. This is the structure of my Controllers folder:

```
Controllers
    /MainController.cs
```

And this is the structure of my Views folder:

```
Views
    /Main
        Index.cshtml
        /Subfolder
            Index.cshtml
            Create.cshtml
```

The index view at the root of the main folder renders it.

```
public class MainController: Controller{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View()
    }
}
```

But when you want to render the page in the sub folder it marks that the view is not found

```
[Router("~/Subfoler")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View("~/Views/Main/Subfolder/Index.cshtml")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of Attribute Routing:

```
[Route("~/Views/Main/Subfolder/Index/{id}")]
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
 //...
 return View();
}
```

You can find more about Attribute Routing at this link [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET MVC 5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/)